# Quetion about windows 8.1 download on microsoft store

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, license, license-key, full-version

I have a quetion about windows 8.1 license agreement (Full retail version/ Personal user license from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/intellectualproperty/UseTerms/default.aspx).

My question is about the following clause -

> Can I transfer the software to another computer or user? You may
>   transfer the software to another computer that belongs to you. You may
>   also transfer the software (together with the license) to a computer
>   owned by someone else if a) you are the first licensed user of the
>   software and b) the new user agrees to the terms of this agreement. To
>   make that transfer, you must transfer the original media, the
>   certificate of authenticity, the product key, and the proof of
>   purchase directly to that other person, without retaining any copies
>   of the software. You may use the backup copy we allow you to make or
>   the media that the software came on to transfer the software. Every
>   time you transfer the software to a new computer, you must remove the
>   software from the prior computer. You may not transfer the software to
>   share licenses between computers. **You may transfer Get Genuine Windows
>   software, Pro Pack or Media Center Pack software only together with
>   the licensed computer**.

What does the bold lines meet

> You may transfer Get Genuine Windows software, Pro Pack or Media
>   Center Pack software only together with the licensed computer.

Basically i want to know , if I install this OS from on one laptop and it crashes or goes bust, will i be able to transfer this os to another laptop and still have a genuine product?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can. As long as you are no longer using the copy of Windows on another PC you may transfer the license legally.

Comment: so what does "You may transfer Get Genuine Windows software, Pro Pack or Media Center Pack software only together with the licensed computer" refer to. What is Get Genuine Windows software?

Comment: it means that nay add ons that you've installed with the genuine copy cannot be transferred seperately. You can only move them with the licensed software to the newly licensed computer.

Comment: Its important to understand that the license key is changed once those upgrades are applied to `Windows Core` or `Windows Pro` installations.  You cannot install `Windows 8 Core` with a `Windows 8 Pro w/Media Center` license key.  There is only a single type of a retail Windows 8.1 license, a full license, which means the license can be transfered.  A Windows 8.1 license on OEM hardware still cannot be transfered to entirely different hardware ( nothing has changed in this regard ).

Comment: So what this caluse means is if you upgrade your retail license, that new license that is created, has to be transfered with the original license.  They cannot exist on two entirely different pieces of hardware, the $10 Media Center license, cannot be used by itself on Computer B while the original license is used on Computer A.  **You still have a single license.**

Comment: Ok - so any software (windows software like upgrade , media centre) that i install on compuetr A will also have to be transfered to computer B. I cannot tranfer the core to windows B and keep the add on licenses on computer A. Am i right?

Comment: Also, just for confirmation the download of windows 8.1 om microsoft store is a full installation one not an upgrade from previous version of windows. Am i right? Just want to be sure that the download will be able to install on a brand new PC (no previous windows OS)